# xmlReader to pull data that matches textbox

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I have an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views ClientCode="WSMCABS">
    <View Name="vACCESSONE">
        <Criteria>ACCESSONE</Criteria>
    </View>
    <View Name="vSample2">
        <Criteria>SAMPLE2</Criteria>
    </View>
</Views>
```

I'm creating a standalone interface that connect to my DB and runs a query. The query returns data  to some textboxes, and I want to show a subchild within the XML file to a textbox based on the text of another textbox.

For example, the textbox1.text shows "vACCESSONE" on form_load

I want textbox2.text to show "ACCESSONE" like in the example xml above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Linq? You could then use code like the following to select the required data:

```
    dim data=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Views ClientCode="WSMCABS">
    <View Name="vACCESSONE">
        <Criteria>ACCESSONE</Criteria>
    </View>
    <View Name="vSample2">
        <Criteria>SAMPLE2</Criteria>
    </View>
</Views>

dim result=data...<View>.where(function(p) p.@Name="vACCESSONE").select(function(p) p.<Criteria>.Value).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to work 2.0 Framework, so LINQ is not an option.